# tktable text garbled when width of cells is too narrow

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit, tktable

using Tktable 2.11 with tk 8.6.9 on Mojave.
when I make a simple table

```
table .t -variable var -rows 4 -cols 2
pack .t
```

if I enter enough text that it doesn't fit, it will appear garbled, sometimes even part of the text showing up in a distant cell. Of course, it is fixed when I resize but I would like it to be cut off. (in fact I think that is what the -ellipsis is to do, but that doesn't seem to have an affect. Besides sometimes I need to have -wrap or -multiline, which don't work with -ellipsis)

Contrast this with the entry widget, which clearly displays partial text when the entire text does not fit

```
entry .e -width 5
.e insert end "123456789"
pack .e
```

In an older version of Tktable that I was using, I did not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in comp.lang.tcl:

> This is a known issue when using Tktable under Cocoa-based Tk Aqua, and has been for several years now. See https://sourceforge.net/p/tktable/bugs/309/
>
> So far the suggested workaround is to use -drawmode slow.

This worked for the text that doesn't fit. Unfortunately, I see it makes all of the text a bit fuzzy - even in cells where the text was fully displayed.

Comment: comp.tcl.lang replier here. I investigated the issue a bit more and believe it's caused by [an issue in Tk Aqua](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/685ac30727) which could be challenging to fix. Tktable could work around it, but the project is dormant. Can you provide screenshots of the fuzzy vs not-fuzzy text either here or on the Tktable bug report? I'm curious what could be causing it, but haven't observed it myself. Do you happen to be using a retina display?

Comment: The fuzzy text indeed appears to be related to drawing to a Retina display. I have followed up on the [Tktable ticket](https://sourceforge.net/p/tktable/bugs/309/#7b1c) as well as opened a new [Tk ticket](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/info/e2e9ce70b2); I don't know of any workarounds for it, though.

Comment: Update: Tk Aqua 8.6.11 will contain a solution for these issues, but taking advantage of it requires recompiling Tktable with a tiny change. See https://sourceforge.net/p/tktable/bugs/309/#22e7 for more info and a patchfile. Once this is done, -drawmode slow should no longer be used in order to avoid the fuzzy text on Retina displays.